# how to export 3 table values to single excel using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need to export 3 full sql table values in to a single excel sheet  using store procedure.
i have done with single table ,

query i have used for single table :

```
   set @sql='bcp "select * from  Veest..ven_machinedescription_day_report " queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S' + @@servername          
   exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql          


   --Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file        
   set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'"'''        
   exec(@sql)        


  --Delete dummy file         
    set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''        
    exec(@sql)
```

the above query is working fine..
for saving 3 tables values , i have done like this ,

```
          set @sql='bcp "select * from  Veest..ven_machinedescription_day_report " queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S' + @@servername          
              exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql  
        set @sql1='bcp "select * from  Veest..ven_machinedescription_night_report " queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S' + @@servername          
       exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql1  
           set @sql22='bcp "select * from  Veest..ven_machinedescription_midnight_report " queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S' + @@servername          
      exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql2
```

when i  saw the  data_file.csv, only the last execution (@sql2) is saved..the data is not being appended.. i need output similar to the below  image..

[image]

some times the total columns numbers  will be not same in all the 3 tables..
plz help me out to solve this issue..

thanks n regards,

T.Navin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view. Then export from the view to Excel.

```
CREATE VIEW vending_report
AS
    SELECT 'A' segment, col1, col2, shift_type, col4, col5, col6
    FROM ven_machinedescription_day_report

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'B', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'C', col1, col2, shift_type, col4, NULL, NULL
    FROM ven_machinedescription_night_report

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'D', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'E', col1, col2, shift_type, col4, col5, NULL
    FROM ven_machinedescription_midnight_report
GO

SELECT col1, col2, shift_type, col4, col5, col6
FROM vending_report
ORDER BY segment
```

Comment: @anthony :i have used the view .. i am getting the output in the excel as a continous one.. i need to have some break between each select statement to differentiate it...

Comment: @navbingo I have added blank rows to the query

Comment: @anthony: another query, i am creating these 3 tables dynamically ..so the number of columns in each table will be different..how to form /create a view for tht..

Comment: @navbingo You should consider using permanent tables that are fully normalized. Dynamic SQL makes everything so much harder.

Comment: @Anthony: according to my project needs i have to create dynamic tables..i have applied the above logic into my permanent table.. and i have some dynamic tables as well